# find all four digit numbers for which the square of the sum of the first two digits and the last two digits equal the number itself

Tags: java, math, conditional-statements

My code should execute all 4 digit numbers, the square of the sum of the first two digits and the last two digits should be equal to the number it self but mine it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (int i = 1000; i <= 9999; i++){
    int n = i;
    int remandier1, remandier2,finalanswer;
    double result1=0;
    while(n != 0){
        remandier1 = n % 100;
        remandier2 = n /100;
        finalanswer = remandier1 + remandier2;
        result1 = Math.pow(finalanswer, 2);
    }
    if (result1 == n){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working? Please state what it's supposed to do, and what it's doing wrong.

Comment: I edited the question but briefly, this program should find all the 4 digit numbers that the square of the sum of the first and last 2 digits equal the number it self. For example 3025. (30+25)^2 = 3025

Comment: From the title it seems that if you have a number in the form of abcd then your conditions should be (a+b)*(a+b)=(d+e)*(d+e)=abde. Sqrt(1000)=31.1 and Sqrt(9999) =99.9. So probably which are larger than a two digit sum. So probably you wanted (ab+de)^2=abce, the loop "while(n != 0)" will never finish since your n is ==i, which is in the range of 1000 .. 9999

Comment: Yes, what I meant was (ab+cd)^2 = abcd.

Comment: remove the "while(n != 0){ " and the corresponding closing brace. Avoid comparing doubles with equals. You might get unexpected results.

Comment: Now it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are using a loop based on `n` being different from 0, but `n` is never modified during the loop. How would the loop could actually stop.. looping ? May be I'm missing something, but as I see it, `n` will forever be equal to the set value of `i`.

```
while(n != 0)
{
    remandier1 = n % 100;
    remandier2 = n /100;
    finalanswer = remandier1 + remandier2;
    result1 = Math.pow(finalanswer, 2);
    // add something to stop the loop
    n = n - 1; // for example
}
```

Comment: When i reaches 9999, the program should stop

Comment: `i` will never reach 9999 as it is stuck in the `while` loop, thus only one iteration of the `for` loop is actually done - and not completely. You need to make sur the `while (n != 0)` stop at one point.